# My class implements interface with methods. which arent implemented but no errors

Tags: java, reflection, interface, extend, implements

I've created dao class that implements an interface with two methods. None of them are implemented in that dao class. I am getting no errors. Everything compiles and works.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my dao class:

```
package com.derp.generic.dao;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.derp.generic.model.GenericDictionaryModel;

@Repository
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericDictionaryModelDaoImpl <T extends GenericDictionaryModel<?>> extends GenericModelDaoImpl implements GenericDictionaryModelDao {
}
```

And here's my interface:

```
package com.derp.generic.dao;

public interface GenericDictionaryModelDao<T> extends GenericModelDao<T>{
    public T getByName(String name);
    public T getByActive(boolean active);
}
```

**REST OF CLASSESS:**

```
package com.derp.generic.dao;

import java.util.List;

public interface GenericModelDao<T> {
    public void add(T entityClass);
    public void update(T entityClass);
    public void delete(long id);
    public T get(long id);
    public List<T> get();
    public String toString();
}

package com.derp.generic.model;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericDictionaryModel<T extends GenericDictionaryModel<?>> extends GenericModel<T> {
    private String name;
    private boolean active;

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public boolean getActive() {return active;}
    public void setActive(boolean stat) {this.active = stat;}
}

package com.derp.generic.model;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericModel<T extends GenericModel<?>> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GenericDictionaryModelDaoImpl` class is abstract, so it doesn't have to implement all the methods of the `GenericDictionaryModelDao` interface. Any concrete class that will inherit from your abstract class would have to implement all the unimplemented methods of that interface.